# jquery show not working in function

Tags: jquery

Can't figure out the problem here. `show()` outside of function `onSelectChange` works good, inside no. Append works good if label is not hidden.
My codes below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#cityfrom").change(onSelectChange);
});
function onSelectChange(){
 var selected = jQuery("#cityfrom option:selected");
 if(selected.val() != 0){
  selectedfrom = selected.text();
  jQuery("#hidden").show();
  jQuery("#append").text(selectedfrom);
 }
}
```

```css
#hidden{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<label id="hidden"><input type="radio" name="start" value="xx"><span id="append"></span></label>
<select id="cityfrom">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Izvēlies citu pilsētu</option>
 <option name="pilseta" value="smiltene">Smiltene</option>
 <option name="pilseta" value="valmiera">Valmiera</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think you forgot part of your code. The `id`s you refere to doesn't exist

Comment: Your code works. It doesn't in the sample because you shouldn't have the `script` tags in the javascript section, you haven't referenced jQuery, and the select you're referring to doesn't exist. Adjusting for all of that, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with your code. The `option:selected` part is superfluous. `jQuery('#cityfrom').val()` will do.

Comment: I don't think this post worth an answer, but only comment that the author should explore jQuery a little bit more. Down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 funamental problems with the snippet you posted (neither actual problems with your code!)

- When you set up your snippet you didnt choose and version of jQuery
- You included `<script>` tags in the javascript pane

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#cityfrom").change(onSelectChange);

  
});

function onSelectChange() {
    var selected = jQuery("#cityfrom option:selected");
    if (selected.val() != 0) {
      selectedfrom = selected.text();
      jQuery("#hidden").show();
      jQuery("#append").text(selectedfrom);
    }
  }
```

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="hidden">
  <input type="radio" name="start" value="xx"><span id="append"></span>
</label>
<select id="cityfrom">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Izvēlies citu pilsētu</option>
  <option name="pilseta" value="smiltene">Smiltene</option>
  <option name="pilseta" value="valmiera">Valmiera</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your last point isn't mandatory, since `onSelectChange` doesn't exist in the current scope, the one from the higher scope will be retrieved.

Comment: @AntoineCombes - you're right - dont know what I was thinking!

Comment: @slc - not working where? In that snippet or in your actual code?

Comment: Actual code isnt working. Replaced all my code with your working snippet. Im out of options. As I said out of function jQuery("#hidden").show(); works good, in that function no.

Comment: okay I will accept your answer because it does work, just not for me